# Why does this code block my main thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I need my `Thread` work independent of `Form`.
For example I have a endless loop in my `Thread`:

```
procedure TCustomThread.doProc;
begin
  repeat
.
.
.
  until (1 = 2);
end;

procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  Synchronize(doProc);
end;
.
.
.
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  thrd : TCustomThread;
begin
  thrd := TCustomThread.Create(True);
  thrd.Resume;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Now, when I click on `Button1`, my `Thread` runs but main `Form` is locked. How can I avoid suspending `Form`?

Comment: don't call Synchronize(doProc); just call DoProc; in TCustomThread.Execute;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to `ProcessMessages` is wrong and should be removed. As a broad and general rule, calls to `ProcessMessages` should be avoided. And this one serves no purpose at all.

The rest of your code simply runs a non-terminating loop. It does so using `Synchronize` which ensures that the non-terminating loop runs on the main thread. Hence the main thread is unable to service its message loop.

The entire purpose of threads is to be able to execute separate threads of execution. By using `Synchronize` you are running all your code in the main thread. Your code is equivalent to placing the non-terminating loop in the main thread.

You want to execute code in a different thread. So you should avoid the call to `Synchronize`. That should only be used for small, quick pieces of work that must execute on the main thread. Typically GUI updates.

Your execute method should be:

```
procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ....
  end;
end;
```

This introduces your loop, but the loop now executes in the thread. You can now add the useful code of your thread inside the body of the loop.

Remember that any use of VCL components must happen on the main thread. And that's where `Synchronize` is to be used.

Comment: That makes no real sense. Each thread is a separate stream of instructions. Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: I don't know! My question is why main Form not response when a Thread is in endless loop (or unlike)? -- Sorry if i can't tell correctly my purpose.

Comment: The answer is good, so I've voted it up, but I think Mohammad still doesn't get it.

Comment: @Mohammad The main form can only be responsive if its message queue is serviced promptly. But its message queue is not serviced at all because the main thread is running your non-terminating loop. I'm not sure that you really understand threads yet. I'm not sure how you are going to get that understanding.

Comment: Maybe another piece of knowledge that you miss is how the Windows message queue works. Do you understand that?

Comment: I think I need more information about Thread and I go to complete this. However, Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

`TThread.Synchronize()` runs the specified procedure in the context of the main thread, not in the context of the worker thread.  So your loop is running in the main thread and is not letting hte main thread process new messages from its message queue.  That is why your UI is not responding while your thread is running.

You need to restructure your thread to something more like this:

```
procedure TCustomThread.doUpdateUI;
begin
  ... do something that updates the UI here ...
end;

procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ... do something in the worker thread ...
    Synchronize(doUpdateUI);
    ... do something else in the worker thread ...
  end;
end;
```

```
var
  thrd : TCustomThread = nil;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if thrd = nil then
    thrd := TCustomThread.Create(False);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if thrd <> nil then
  begin
    thrd.Terminate;
    thrd.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(thrd);
  end;
end;
```